# Ubuntu 18.04 not copying correctly?

Tags: upgrade

I have 14.0xxx and tried to upgrade to 18 but coping the iso the a USB it said to "bootloader was not copied across. Can I use the USB?

Comment: How were you creating the USB?  If you weren't using USB Startup Disk Creator or Rufus or similar, then your USB stick is likely not going to boot.\

Answer (score 2):

To create a bootable USB drive, you need to use a special tool to put the ISO on it. Simply copying and pasting it like a normal file won't work.

You can use `dd` to do this. Open a terminal and use this command:

```
lsblk
```

This will give you a list of your drives. Then use this command:

```
sudo dd if=/path/to/your/file/here.iso of=/dev/sdX
```

Replace `/dev/sdX` with your flash drive and make the `if=` point to your ISO file.

Comment: trebor@symsr8:~$ sudo dd if=/home/trebor/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/sdb/sdb1
dd: failed to open ‘/sdb/sdb1’: No such file or directory

Comment: trebor@symsr8:~$ lsblk
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda      8:0    0 119.2G  0 disk 
├─sda1   8:1    0 116.4G  0 part /
├─sda2   8:2    0     1K  0 part 
└─sda5   8:5    0   2.9G  0 part [SWAP]
sdb      8:16   1  28.9G  0 disk 
└─sdb1   8:17   1  28.9G  0 part /media/trebor/USB G4
loop0    7:0    0   1.8G  1 loop /tmp/tmpb22jmeh1
loop1    7:1    0   1.8G  1 loop /tmp/tmpne50qnty

Comment: No numbers, just the letter.

Comment: Can you explain no numbers?

Comment: `sudo dd if=/home/trebor/Downloads/ubuntu-18.04.1-desktop-amd64.iso of=/dev/sdb`